# I have a jcb corded drill that seems to have suddenly stopped working

Tags: electrical, drill

The drill is in pretty good condition and worked when used last a few months ago. It is now not working when pressing the trigger. It will randomly have a bust of power and start then when the trigger isn't being pressed shortly after it was pressed. Any ideas or is it ready for the bin?

Comment: Another possibility is an internal break in the cable - usually close to the handle...

Answer (score 1):

Might be worn out brushes, which should be a $5 fix, but the actual price will depend on the specific drill and parts suppliers - as will how easy or difficult it is. Can be a 2-minute job (nice externally accessible brush caps), can take 30 when you have ot open the whole case up to get to them.

Might also be a bad switch, which is usually more money and more time to change out.

Third possibility is a loose wire connection.